# How can i move a Redshift Snapshot from S3 to Glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-glacier

I would like to shut down my Redshift cluster but would like to keep a backup of it.
I understood i can create a Manual Snapshot and it will be save to S3.
To reduce the costs even more, i would like to **move the Snapshot from S3 to Glacier** but can't find the Snapshot in my S3 account.

Where is the Snapshot being saved? Is AWS keeping it in a different account?

Or maybe i am not at all going the right way, should i be backing up my Redshift cluster differently?

Thank you,
Oren.

Answer (score 7):

It's not stored in any of your account's S3 buckets. It's being stored "behind the scenes" in S3. Amazon only makes a point of telling you it is stored in S3 so you understand the fault-tolerance involved in the storage of your snapshots. If you need to store a backup in one of your S3 buckets you would need to do a `pg_dump` of the database and copy the dump file to S3.

Comment: Making my comment an answer.

Comment: Tahnks Mark, should i be worried about size while using pg_dump? what if my cluster is more than 300GB? would that work?

Comment: As long as you have plenty of free space on your EBS drive where you are saving the dump.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Redshift's [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) to dump tables straight to an S3 bucket. Unfortunately you need to do it separately for each table. You'll also want to archive all the schema queries, `CREATE`, etc. for your tables (the `pg_dump` solution doesn't have this problem since it can capture the table definitions, but requires local storage of the files and manual push to S3...might be worth it though for a case like archive and complete shutdown).

```
UNLOAD('select * from your_table') TO 's3://your_bucket/your_table.csv' 
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=YOUR_KEY;aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET' 
DELIMITER ',' NULL 'null' ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

Once you have all your tables in an S3 bucket you can set the lifecycle (rules created in the Properties pane of the bucket on the Lifecycle panel) to archive to glacier storage class.

It's a bit confusing because Glacier is it's own service, but when you archive via lifecycle the files stay in the S3 bucket. You can tell they're in glacier by selecting a file in the S3 console, selecting the `properties` pane and opening the `Details` panel. There is should say `Storage class: Glacier`.

If you ever need to restore you'll use the [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command:

```
COPY your_table FROM 's3://your_bucket/your_table.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=[YOURKEY];aws_secret_access_key=[YOURSECRET]'
DELIMITER ',' NULL 'null' IGNOREBLANKLINES EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL TIMEFORMAT 'auto' FILLRECORD MAXERROR 1
```